# Upload form-data not hitting the controller action method right after uploading to ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, multipartform-data

I've upload a file to an ASP.NET Core Web API from my C# httpclient
but the problem is the form-data does not hit the controller action method until the form uploading finishes!

I've written a middleware that captures requests and I can see the form-data request is hitting the middleware right after I press the upload button from my desktop application.

The question is: how can I make the request hit the action method right after I press the upload button and not wait until every part of file has been streamed?

Comment: Can you provide your current code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.